# Reduce or prevent calling of update_meta_cache

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, pre-get-posts

My theme calls the update_meta_cache() function 58 times per page! This function appears to run the following query based on the post in question:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value
-> FROM wp_postmeta
-> WHERE post_id IN (81649)
-> ORDER BY meta_id ASC
-> ;
```

The vast majority of the meta_keys (and corresponding values) returned are not necessary for the page in question (e.g. yoast_wpseo_title, _edit_last, _edit_lock are not needed for the homepage loop).

Is there a way to reduce or prevent calling of the update_meta_cache? Perhaps a way to include in a function on the pre_get_posts hook?

Comment: Just a sidenote: [Explanation of update_post_(meta/term)_cache](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215871/explanation-of-update-post-meta-term-cache).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use the function `get_post_meta()`, the above query will be performed to get *all* post meta and store in the cache. The more posts you query, the more queries are made.

To reduce the number of queries, we should **pre-cache all meta values of all posts** in the query before calling `get_post_meta`.

This is the sample code taken from [a tutorial](http://hitchhackerguide.com/2011/11/01/reducing-postmeta-queries-with-update_meta_cache/):

```php
add_filter( 'posts_results', 'cache_meta_data', 9999, 2 );
function cache_meta_data( $posts, $object ) {
    $posts_to_cache = array();
    // this usually makes only sense when we have a bunch of posts
    if ( empty( $posts ) || is_wp_error( $posts ) || is_single() || is_page() || count( $posts ) < 3 )
        return $posts;

    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        if ( isset( $post->ID ) && isset( $post->post_type ) ) {
            $posts_to_cache[$post->ID] = 1;
        }
    }

    if ( empty( $posts_to_cache ) )
        return $posts;

    update_meta_cache( 'post', array_keys( $posts_to_cache ) );
    unset( $posts_to_cache );

    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: I just came across this issue, as I'm seeing a ton of `update_meta_cache()` requests being made. With this tweak in my themes function.php file, I'm still seeing lots of these kind of queries? `SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (8987) ORDER BY meta_id ASC` ... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No effect whatsoever, it's bad idea to use random 2011 code on latest wp so much changed.

Comment: I simply searched "update_meta_cache" in "whole world press folder" and terminated.. Now website is running like i'm using offline.. super fast.

Comment: **DON'T CACHE ALL (SITE) POSTS AT ONCE** - what author means here are all posts fetched for a particular page, don't attempt to pre-cache hundreds, thousands, mlions etc. of posts, it could kill your site, if you need extensive caching, use per-page caching solution or plugin. *(the bold text just seems misleading for random-newcomers)*

Comment: Hi @MFarooqi could you elaborate a little bit further how you fixed that? I'm still having the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

For a `WP_Query`, caching can be disabled by setting certain [caching parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#caching-parameters) to `false`.

Similarly for `WP_Term_Query`, it can be disabled by including `update_term_meta_cache => false` in the query args.

Additionally, the filter [update_{$meta_type}_metadata_cache](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_meta_type_metadata_cache/) can be used to disable metadata caching for all queries on the object type. (ex. `update_post_metadata_cache`, `update_term_metadata_cache`, etc)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @plong0, this seems to be exactly the thing I've been looking for. Fun experiments with less meta caching await me :)