# Is define('WP_CACHE', true) needed for object caching?

Tags: cache

I am just reading the docs at https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache and am not clear on something...

If I install an object cache plugin by adding the drop-in file *object-cache.php* to the *wp-content* directory do I need to add `define('WP_CACHE', true)` to my *wp-config.php* file to activate caching or will the drop-in file just start interacting with the cache by its mere presence?

Comment: I'm almost certain that [object caching is on by default](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215881/7355) and you don't need to add anything special.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, including this constant with a value of `true` loads advanced-cache.php. Object-cache.php is loaded and used automatically.

See https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/

Comment: Good share... note that some incorrect tutorials are floating around in the wild, even from large companies like Alibaba: https://www.alibabacloud.com/tech-news/cache/1ma-how-to-use-memcached-with-wordpress