# Should wp_query automatic meta and term cache priming be used in an enviroment with an object caching

Tags: wp-query, performance, cache

This is kind of followup question to [Explanation of update_post_(meta/term)_cache](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215871/explanation-of-update-post-meta-term-cache) which discusses the disabling of automatic meta and term caches by setting to `false` both `update_post_meta_cache` and `update_post_term_cache` argument of `wp_Query`.

The question is, if we assume that for most queries all the posts being returned are already primed in the cache, and only the minority of them have some additional posts, does it make more sense to assume that the cache will be primed and skip the meta and term queries, or is it better to just assume the worst case and prime everything regardless?

To make it slightly less vague lets put a ratio of 9 (90%) full hits on 1 (10%) partial miss, and average of 50 results per query.